# Inheritance scenario in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop

I have the following code in Ruby:

```
class Base
  def Function1
    puts 'Base Function1'
  end

  def Function2
    Function1
  end
end

class Derived < Base
  def Function1
    puts 'Derived Function1'
  end
end

obj = Derived.new
obj.Function2
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error:

```
/Users/vkuppuswamy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/vkuppuswamy/RubymineProjects/TestRubyProj/TestRuby.rb
/Users/vkuppuswamy/RubymineProjects/TestRubyProj/TestRuby.rb:7:in `Function2': uninitialized constant Base::Function1 (NameError)
    from /Users/vkuppuswamy/RubymineProjects/TestRubyProj/TestRuby.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I can see that the in `Function2` in class `Base`, an attempt has been made to call some constant `Function1`. I do not see why this would happen. I thought the derived class `Function1` method will be invoked. When I change the `Function2` in the base class to:

```
  def Function2
    self.Function1
  end
```

where I invoke `Function1` using `self`, it works, and I get in output:

```
Derived Function1
```

Can you please help me understand why this is happening. I thought the `self` was implicit in Ruby.

Comment: Conventions in Ruby are that Constants start with a Capital letter, while methods are lowercase. Try calling your functions `function1` etc. What happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constants (this includes `class`es) are written in `UpperCase`, methods/functions are written in `lowercase`. This has nothing to do with inheritance, consider:

```
def Foo
  puts 'Foo'
end

Foo
# NameError: uninitialized constant Foo
```

This happens because when Ruby sees an uppercase token, it looks for a constant and that's it. You *could* explicitly tell Ruby to look for a method by using parentheses `()` but just **don't do it**:

```
Foo()
# Foo
```

Use lowercase method names instead. Then, your code will work as expected:

```
class Base
  def function1
    puts 'Base function1'
  end

  def function2
    function1
  end
end

class Derived < Base
  def function1
    puts 'Derived function1'
  end
end

obj = Derived.new
obj.function2
```

This prints

```
Derived function1
```